# Django admin linking me to a template

Tags: python, django, web, django-templates, django-admin

When programming locally on my development server, the site is functioning as expected. But when I go to my production site, a handful of the links in mysite.com/admin link me to a random template that's extending my base.html, rather than the typical database/form UI.

**Here's the mysite.urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('account/logout/', views.logout, name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
    path('', include('website.urls')),
]
```

**My website.urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
    path('community/', views.growing_communities_page, name='growing_communities_page'),
    path('recommend_a_friend/', views.signup, name='recommend_a_friend'),
    path('about/', views.about_page, name='about'),
    path('donate_to_feed/', views.donate_to_feed, name='donate_to_feed'),
    path('sign_up/', views.sign_up, name='sign_up'),
    path('profit_sharing/', views.profit_sharing, name='profit_sharing'),
    path('we_identify/', views.we_identify, name='we_identify'),
    path('account/', views.account, name='account'),
    path('community_page/<slug>/', views.community_page, name='community_page'),

    path('farm/<slug>/', views.farm_page, name='farm_page'),
    path('farm/<slug>/review/', views.add_comment_to_farm, name='add_comment_to_farm'),

    path('farmersmarket/<slug>/', views.farmersmarket_page, name='farmersmarket_page'),
    path('farmersmarket/<slug>/review/', views.add_comment_to_farmersmarket, name='add_comment_to_farmersmarket'),

    path('grocer/<slug>/', views.grocer_page, name='grocer_page'),
    path('grocer/<slug>/review/', views.add_comment_to_grocer, name='add_comment_to_grocer'),

    path('producer/<slug>/', views.producer_page, name='producer_page'),
    path('producer/<slug>/review/', views.add_comment_to_producer, name='add_comment_to_producer'),

    path('restaurant/<slug>/', views.restaurant_page, name='restaurant_page'),
    path('restaurant/<slug>/review/', views.add_comment_to_restaurant, name='add_comment_to_restaurant'),

    path('wellness/<slug>/', views.wellness_page, name='wellness_page'),
    path('wellness/<slug>/review/', views.add_comment_to_wellness, name='add_comment_to_wellness'),
]
```

**And website.admin.py**
    admin.site.register(Community)

```
admin.site.register(Farm)
admin.site.register(FarmReview)
admin.site.register(Livestock)

admin.site.register(Farmersmarket)
admin.site.register(FarmersmarketReview)

admin.site.register(Grocer)
admin.site.register(GrocerReview)

admin.site.register(Producer)
admin.site.register(ProducerReview)

admin.site.register(Restaurant)
admin.site.register(RestaurantReview)

admin.site.register(Wellness)
admin.site.register(WellnessReview)

admin.site.register(MenuItem)
admin.site.register(MenuCategory)

admin.site.register(GrocerMenuItem)
admin.site.register(GrocerMenuCategory)

admin.site.register(Monday)
admin.site.register(Tuesday)
admin.site.register(Wednesday)
admin.site.register(Thursday)
admin.site.register(Friday)
admin.site.register(Saturday)
admin.site.register(Sunday)

admin.site.register(Address)

admin.site.register(ValueAddedProducts)
admin.site.register(Business)
admin.site.register(ProductsAvaiableAt)

admin.site.register(Map)
admin.site.register(Calendar)
admin.site.register(Communityspirit)
admin.site.register(Certifying_Organizations)

admin.site.register(About)
```

**For example, I expect clicking something in this menu:**
[image]

**Will link me to this page:**
 [image]

**But instead, I am getting:**
 [image]

Any help would be great.

Comment: You haven't said what link is taking you there, where that link is shown, or posted any of the code for your URLs or your admin.

Comment: Sorry. Just updated it with the code requested.

Comment: The last screenshot is from your homepage? The restaurant_page?